# Disappearing Views

Tags: android, xml

I have a fairly standard layout for the first screen of the setup wizard on my app. I have been developing it with a solid color background which I defined in a theme. I have recently got a png file that I would like to used as the background. This works fine on all screens apart from the 3 screens for the setup wizard. The problem being that only the first textview is drawn. I used the hierachy viewer and the other views where not listed.

These are the only screens that use an include statement so I suspect this may be the root of the problem but even if I take out the include statement I still have the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#433A33"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>
   <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/mainIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/main_icon" 
        android:layout_width="100dip"  
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcome">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainIcon"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#433A33"
        android:textSize="15dip">
  </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choice"
        android:layout_below="@id/description"
        android:text="@string/choice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#433A33"
        android:textSize="15dip">
  </TextView>
     <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/language" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/choice"
        android:prompt="@string/languagePrompt"
        android:textSize="10dip" 
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip">
    </Spinner>

  <include layout="@layout/wizard_bottom"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if anybody has any ideas.

**Edited to show the problem with a screen shot**

[image]

Comment: Hi Jiduvah can you please ellaborate your problem regarding backbround. I am unable to understand the problem

Comment: @Deepak there is a screen shot to highlight the problem

Comment: in the screenshot what is the problem, I want to know.whether the background image is not set or anything else?

Comment: @Deepak Well it is only shoing the first textview. I just figured it out tho. I have a theme that sets the background to the image. So it was setting everything in the view to have this background, so the background that we can see is actually the background of the textview

Comment: If that theme is written to use fill_parent then yout other TextView will not be visible. please check that theme along with the size of png file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the theme I was using was setting the background to all Views rather than just the window background. So the background that is in the screen shot is the background for that one imageView and all the other views where pushed off the page.

I changed the them accordingly and it working fine now